# Is this an accepted way of using an effect in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-signals

I have an Angular directive and a signal gets values from a store selector. This signal should define if a button is disabled or not. What would be the accepted way of listening on this signal, can I use the effect (bad practice?) or something else?

This is my directive, the effect is in the constructor and I tried with `ngOnChanges` (which was a piece of old code that I adapted, before I used a signal). `MaintenanceDisableErp` is a signal that comes from a selector.

I read from [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/signals) that signals can be used for *"Adding custom DOM behavior that can't be expressed with template syntax"*. Is this what it was meant for?

```
import {
  Directive,
  Input,
  HostListener,
  Renderer2,
  ElementRef,
  inject,
  effect,
} from "@angular/core";
import { MatSnackBar } from "@angular/material/snack-bar";
import { NotificationService } from "@core/services/notification.service";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { toSignal } from "@angular/core/rxjs-interop";
import { selectDisabledErp } from "@core/_state/core.reducer";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appErpDisabled]",
})
export class DisableNotifyDirective {
  store = inject(Store);
  maintenanceDisableErp = toSignal(this.store.select(selectDisabledErp));

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    effect(() => {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(
        this.el.nativeElement,
        "disabled",
        this.maintenanceDisableErp() ? "true" : "false"
      );
    });
  }

  // ngOnChanges() {
  //   if (this.maintenanceDisableErp()) {
  //     this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "disabled", "true");
  //   } else {
  //     this.renderer.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "disabled", "false");
  //   }
  // }
}
```

Comment: i tested it and it works flawlessly, but the question still stands

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a host binding in you case so you don't have to play with the renderer (The renderer should be avoid when possible):

```
export class DisableNotifyDirective {
  store = inject(Store);

  @HostBinding('disabled') shouldDisable = false

  constructor() {
    this.store.select(selectDisabledErp).pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(disabled) {
      this.shouldDisable = disabled
    }
  }
}
```

---

Edit: To answer your initial question,
`effect()` only works with signals. It gets called when the signal gets updated. [See the docs](https://angular.io/guide/signals#effects)

Comment: ok, very helpful, i am going to use that. But the actual question with the signals is left unanswered. Can/Should i use the effect with the signals method (even if its still very new) or the rxjs variant like the answer?

Comment: `effect()` only works with signals, see my edit !

Comment: yes, i am using signals like i already explained, signals are being used, therefore i am asking if it's bad practice

Comment: `effect()` is the way to go, if you want to do a side effect on a signal change. The only bad practice I see in your code is the use of the `renderer`.